# Markups Core enterEditMode() returning false

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

```
function newMarkupGUI(viewer, options) {

  Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);
  thisViewerId = options.id;
  this.viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then(() => {
    let extension = this.viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
    extension.enterEditMode();
    console.log(extension.enterEditMode());
  });
  
}
```

When I am inside my main js file where I initialize the viewer, I am able to access functions such as **enterEditMode()** like so:

```
var extension = viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");

extension.enterEditMode();
```

This works. But inside my extension called **newMarkupsGUI**, it seems **getExtension()** does not work. I am confused about how this all works, as the documentation is pretty sparse. I would rather keep my extension *separate* and not hard code the functionality of markups where I am initializing the viewer. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the **viewer** reference. You don't need to use `this.viewer` if you have your `viewer` as function parameter.

When using `viewer.loadExtension().then()` the loaded extension is returned in the promise.
You can do something like that :

```
  viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then((markupExtension) => 
  {
    markupExtension.enterEditMode();
  });
```